# Mongoose Trying to populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-design

I have some issues

1. Cant populate CartProduct, just show the ObjectId.
2. There is way to make every time that CartProduct create, add automatically to? cart.
3. is this the right way of schemas structure?

Cart

```
 const CartSchema = new Schema({
  active: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true },
  createAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
 products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "CartProduct" }],
 });

 const Cart = model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

Cart Product

```
const CartProductSchema = new Schema({
item: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product", required: true },
cart: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Cart", required: true },
quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
totalPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
});

const CartProduct = model("CartProduct", CartProductSchema);
```

Product

```
 const ProductSchema = new Schema({
 name: { type: String, required: true },
 price: { type: Number, required: true },
 image: { type: String, required: true },
 category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category", require: true },
  });

 const Product = model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

Cart Controller

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const { userId } = req.body;
   const cart = await Cart.findOne({ client: userId 
  }).populate("CartProduct");

   if (cart === null) {
     const newCart = new Cart({
       client: userId,
     });

    await newCart.save();

   return res.status(201).send({ cart: newCart });
  }

   res.status(200).send({ cart });
 } catch (error) {
   res.status(500).send(error);
   }
  });
```

Add Product to Cart

```
router.post("/addProductToCart", async (req, res) => {
try {
const { item, cart, quantity, price } = req.body;

const newProduct = new CartProduct({
  item,
  cart,
  quantity,
  totalPrice: price * quantity,
});

await newProduct.save();

await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: cart },
  { $push: { products: newProduct } },
  {
    new: true,
  }
);

res.status(201).send({ message: "New Product Added To Cart" });
} catch (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error);
}
});
```

adding product to cart does working,
but populate not working

adding the output

```
{
"cart": {
    "active": true,
    "products": [
        "602bc081daf867167c2eb5da"
    ],
    "_id": "602aab802f625d1654805ef0",
    "client": "601c50211c94cf5d642c67fb",
    "createAt": "2021-02-15T17:12:32.997Z",
    "__v": 0
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your missing `{` in cartSchema

```
 const CartSchema = new Schema({
  active: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true },
  createAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
 products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "CartProduct" }],
 });
```

export the the models like this

```
module.exports = Cart
```

> There is way to make every time that CartProduct create, add automatically to? cart

there is not a automatic way for adding new `_id` of `CartProduct` to `collection`, so you should use  `findOneAndUpdate()` or `find()` and `push in to products array` and `save()`

> is this the right way of schemas structure

yes, It is.

so for populate you can try:

```
let resultCarts = await Cart.find(filter).populate("products")
let resultProducts = await Product.find(filter).populate("category")
```

so change the `CartProduct` to  `products` because you should pass name of field as a argument not name of schema

```
await Cart.findOne({ client: userId 
  }).populate("products");
```

Comment: I'm exporting just like you mention,

the curly bracket is exist in code, only here i forgot to add it

Comment: shokran ya zalame

Comment: the populate still not working.. I'm checking for mistakes

Comment: Its kind of hard to tell exactly what is happening with you code, please provide more code, add controller to the question